# AWS how to Trigger mediaconvert after video upload automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

I am new to AWS. Most of example I have seen need an input file name from S3 bucket for media convert. I want to automate this process. What is the best way to do it. I want to achieve following.

1. API to upload a video(mp4) to a S3 bucket.
2. Trigger MediaConvert Job to process newly updated video and convert it to HLS.

I know how to create an API as well as MediaConvert job. What I need help with it is automating this workflow. How can I pass recently uploaded video to MediaConvert job dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

I think this should actually cover what you're looking for, and is straight from the source:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/vod-automation-part-1-create-a-serverless-watchfolder-workflow-using-aws-elemental-mediaconvert/

Essentially, you'll be making use of AWS Lambda, a serverless code execution product.  Lambda functions by allowing you to hook directly into "triggers" or events from within the AWS ecosystem (like uploading a file to S3).

The lambda can then execute code in a number of supported languages like Javascript or Python, which can be used to execute a MediaConvert job on the triggering object (the file uploaded to S3).